# React.cloneElement: pass new children or copy props.children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I'm confused by the third "children" parameter of `React.cloneElement` and it's relation to `this.props.children`.

I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.kr2laetcn) on higher order components and have the following code:

```
render() {
    const elementsTree = super.render()

    let myPropChange = {}

    /* work on newProps... */
    myPropChange.something = "nice!".

    const newProps = Object.assign({}, elementsTree.props, myPropChange)

    /* map children */
    const newChildren = React.Children.map(elementsTree.props.children, c => something(c))

    return React.cloneElement(elementsTree, newProps, newChildren)
}
```

- Should I put the mapped children into my `newProps.children` or should I pass them as the third parameter to `cloneElement`?
- `Object.assign` copied the children from `props` to `newProps` anyway, should I skip them?
- In the guide it says

  > Components don’t have a guaranty of having the full children tree resolved.

  What does that mean in my situation? That `this.props.children` is not there?
- Added 4th question: Why should I clone the props at all and not just directly edit them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I put the mapped children into my `newProps.children` or should I pass them as the third parameter to `cloneElement`?

Either should be fine.

> `Object.assign` copied the children from `props` to `newProps` anyway, should I skip them?

When using cloneElement, you don't need to copy the props yourself. You can just do `React.cloneElement(elementsTree, {something: 'nice!'})`.

> In the guide it says "Components don’t have a guaranty of having the full children tree resolved." What does that mean in my situation? That this.props.children is not there?

I can't be sure what that article meant, but I believe the author means that your component can choose not to use `this.props.children`. For example, if you render `<Foo><Bar /></Foo>`, then `Foo` will receive `<Bar />` in `this.props.children`, but if `Foo` doesn't use `this.props.children` in its render method, then `Bar` will never be rendered.

> Why should I clone the props at all and not just directly edit them?

React elements are immutable and there's no way you can change the props after an element is created. This allows some performance optimizations in React which wouldn't be possible otherwise.

Comment: So two follow-up questions: 1. If cloneElement merges the passed props with the old props, what happens if I pass `React.cloneElement(elementsTree, {children: ELEMENT}` will the old children be replaced?

Comment: 2. "there's no way you can change the props after an element is created." So can I edit the props object in my HOC-render method directly, and add key/values?

Comment: 1. Yes, they would. 2. No, `this.props` is a frozen object.

Comment: If I pass nothing as third parameter AND no `children` property in my new props, children won't get copied over, is that correct behaviour? I thought they were part of the props …