# How to allow child component to react to a routing event before the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using react, react-router & redux. The structure of my app is such:

```
CoreLayout
  -> <MaterialToolbar /> (contains back button)
  -> {children} (react-router)
```

When the user presses the back button, which is normally handled by the CoreLayout, I would like the current child component to handle the back button instead of the parent. (In my case, I would like the current view to check if its data has been modified, and pop up an 'Are you sure you wish to cancel?' box before actually going back.) If the child does not wish to handle this, the parent will do it's thing.

Another example would be allowing a `childview` to set the title in the toolbar.

My reading has told me that accessing a component through a ref and calling a method on it is not the react way -- this is also made a bit more difficult since I am using redux-connect. What is the correct way to implement this behavior?

Comment: Are you talking about the browser back button, or a back button on your navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it, assuming you mean your navigation back button (and not the browser back button):

```
class CoreLayout extends Component {

    handleBack () {
        //... use router to go back
    }

    render () {
        return <div>
            <MaterialToolbar />
            {React.children.map(this.props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { onBack: this.handleBack }))}
        </div>  
    }
}

class Child extends Component {

    handleBackButtonClick () {
        // Here perform the logic to decide what to do 
        if (dataHasBeenModifiedAndConfirmed) {
            // Yes, user wants to go back, call function passed by the parent
            this.props.onBack()
        } else {
            // User didn't confirm, decide what to do
        }
    }


    render () {
        return <div onClick={this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this)}>
            Go Back
        </div>
    }
}
```

You simply pass a function from the parent to the child via props. Then in the child you can implement the logic to check if you really want to delegate the work to the parent component.

Since you use react-router and your children are passed to your parent component through `this.props.children`, to pass the `onBack` function you need to map the children and use `React.cloneElement` to pass your props (see this answer if you need more details on that: [React.cloneElement: pass new children or copy props.children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120956/react-cloneelement-pass-new-children-or-copy-props-children)).

**Edit:**

Since it seems you want to let the children decide, you can do it this way (using refs):

```
class CoreLayout extends Component {

    constructor () {
        super()
        this.childRefs = {};
    }

    handleBack () {
        for (let refKey in Object.keys(this.childRefs) {
            const refCmp = this.childRefs[refKey];
            // You can also pass extra args to refCmp.shouldGoBack if you need to
            if (typeof refCmp.shouldGoBack === 'function' && !refCmp.shouldGoBack()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // No child requested to handle the back button, continue here...
    }

    render () {
        return <div>
            <MaterialToolbar />
            {React.children.map(this.props.children, (child, n) => React.cloneElement(child, { 
                ref: cmp => { this.childRefs[n] = cmp; }
            }))}
        </div>  
    }
}

class Child extends Component {

    shouldGoBack () {
        // Return true/false if you do/don't want to actually go back
        return true
    }


    render () {
        return <div>
            Some content here
        </div>
    }
}
```

This is a bit more convoluted as normally with React it's easier/more idiomatic to have a "smart" parent that decides based on the state, but given your specific case (back button in the parent and the logic in the children) and without reimplementing a few other things, I think using refs this way is fine.

Alternatively (with Redux) as the other answer suggested, you would need to set something in the Redux state from the children that you can use in the parent to decide what to do.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the issue. The problem arises when the the element that is clicked does not belong to the child, it belongs to the CoreLayout. The CoreLayout then need to ask it's children, will you handle this, or should I?

Comment: I see. That's what I feared. Part of the problem with using the approach is that I am using injectIntl, as well as connect. This means, some views require either: this.childRef.shouldGoBack or this.childRef.getWrappedInstance().shouldGoBack or even this.childRef.getWrappedInstance().getWrappedInstance().shouldGoBack. No easy way for the parent to know which to use. Kinda messy:(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a correct way to solve this problem, but there *are many ways*. If I understand your problem correctly, most of the time the back button `onClick` handler will be handled within `CoreLayout`, but when a particular child is rendered that child will handle the `onClick` event. This is an interesting problem, because the ability to change the functionality of the back button needs to be globally available, or at very least available in `CoreLayout` and the particular child component.

I have not used redux, but I have used Fluxible and am familar with the Flux architecture and the pub/sub pattern.

Perhaps you can utilize your redux store to determine the functionality of your back button. And your `CoreLayout` component would handle rendering the prompt. There is a bug with the following code, but I thought I would not delete my answer for the sake of giving you an idea of what I am talking about and hopefully the following code does that. You would need to think through the logic to get this working correctly, but the idea is there. Use the store to determine what the back button will do.

```
//Core Layout

componentDidMount() {
    store.subscribe(() => {
        const state = store.getState();

        // backFunction is a string correlating to name of function in Core Layout Component
        if(state.backFunction) {

            // lets assume backFunction is 'showModal'. Execute this.showModal()
            // and let it handle the rest.
            this[state.backFunction]();

            // set function to false so its not called everytime the store updates.
            store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BACK_FUNCTION', data: false})
        }
    })
}

showModal() {
    // update state, show modal in Core Layout
    if(userWantsToGoBack) {
        this.onBack();

        // update store backFunction to be the default onBack
        store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BACK_FUNCTION', data: 'onBack'})

    // if they don't want to go back, hide the modal
    } else {
        // hide modal
    }
}

onBack() {
    // handle going back when modal doesn't need to be shown
}
```

The next step is to update your store when the child component mounts

```
// Child component
componentDidMount(){

    // update backFunction so when back button is clicked the appropriate function will be called from CoreLayout
    store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BACK_FUNCTION', data: 'showModal'});
}
```

This way you don't need to worry about passing any function to your child component you let the state of the store determine which function `CoreLayout` will call.